# Set changed size during iteration & threading

Tags: python, python-2.x

I've got a set I'm `while True` looping over on one thread, and on another thread I occasionally need to add or discard items belonging to the set. What's a good way to do this and avoid using a try/except (this method disrupts the rest of the method and essentially causes a 'hitch' in my program)? What I have so far is pretty janky. It's a complicated mess that I can't easily paste in here, so here's a brief description of what I do.

When a new item needs to be added to the dictionary I add the item to a temporary list. I then have a check at the end of my main iteration to see if there is anything in the list, and if so, to go through the process of adding them. Once that's complete, I then reassign the temp list to a blank list to accept new items that may need to be added. I do this same thing for items needing to be removed as well. So, again, sorry for no code. It's a real mess. Any thoughts on how to do this better?

Comment: Create a `threading.Lock()` object and use it to control access to the set.

Comment: I just looked up docs on locking. What would be a good way to set up a queue for this? If I lock the thread, then when the program does its one attempt to remove the object it will fail. Once the thread has been released all the objects that needed to be removed will still need to be. I like this idea, just not sure about queueing.

Comment: You don't lock threads, you put locks on shared resources to prevent problems arising from simultaneous access, which in this case would be your list. However, since now you're talking about a queue, I suggest you use the built-in [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#Queue) class which was designed precisely for exchanging information safely between multiple threads -- in other words, it does any locking needed for you.

Comment: And why are you not accessing the dict directly? dict['item'] = value to add, del dict['item'] to delete.

Comment: @NickWoodhams: Because in a multi-threaded environment one thread might be in the middle of adding or deleting something when another comes along and tries to do one something to it at the same time the data structure gets messed-up or an incorrect value is read.

Comment: @jtsmith1287: Specifically, take a look at the [`Queue.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#Queue.Queue.get) method and its variations for removing objects.

Comment: @martineau Post an answer so I can select it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, consider using an instance of the [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) module's `Queue` class to pass information between the different threads running in your program. The module implements several kinds of queues, so you can select the one most appropriate for what you're doing, and it synchronizes access to them.

The `Queue` class was designed for multi-threaded programming, so its methods automatically handle all required locking details for you, thereby preventing simultaneous access problems which I think are what you're describing in your question.

For example, it possible to test whether a queue is full or empty, alleviating the need to use try/except clause when retrieving items. Alternatively a `Queue`'s a `get()` method will optionally block and possibly timeout if desired.

Sorry, without some sample code for what you're actually trying to do, I'm unable to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For `set_name = set()`, `set_name.discard(element)` won't raise an exception if the element doesn't exist.

Edit:

```
help(set.discard)

discard(...)
    Remove an element from a set if it is a member.

    If the element is not a member, do nothing.
```